# Javascript. Can't get element style

Tags: javascript, width, element

I'm trying to get width & height of the img element. It gives 0px whatever I do.

```
function foo(element){
if(element){
    var el=document.querySelector(element);
    var img=el.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    alert(img.style.width);
}
}
foo();
```

And the html:

```
<div id="theid" class="theclass">
   <img id="img" alt="img" name="the img" src="img/img.jpg" />
</div>

<script>
foo("#theid");
</script>
```

I've also tried `.offsetWidth`, `.clientWidth` and `defaultView.getComputedStyle(img,"");`

Comment: You haven't specify style attribute for img tag. So obviously you wont get width of the img.

Comment: Assuming your image is actually rendering ok, press F12 (in Chrome / IE / possibly others) to bring up "developer tools", and take a look at its full suite of properties. It should help.

Comment: yes, ofcourse. it is interesting that there is not properties of img element. but there is a css file that cointains the img object

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
function foo(imgId){
    var img=document.getElementById(imgId);
    alert(img.offsetWidth);
}

foo('img');
```

Comment: I've amended things. The 'id' should be unique, in which case you are safe to use this.

Comment: Is the image actually rendering ok?  Can you provide an example, e.g. jsFiddle?  Have you used your browsers developer tools to inspect the element - it should give you all the properties of your img, and hopefully shed some light on why its reporting 0 width.

Comment: WOW. works great on jsFiddle - gives 18. But on desktop gives 0 ... This is kidding with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="theid" class="theclass">
   <img id="img" alt="img" name="the img" src="img/img.jpg" />
</div>

<script>
    foo("#theimg");
</script>
```

You are calling foo() by passing #theimg which is not present in document, call by passing #img , i.e. like this

```
<script>
    foo("#img");
</script>
```

if you use above img id, remove var img=el.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]; in your function, we can directly access it.Okay

```
<script>
    foo("#theid");
</script>
```

use this to keep your function as it is. Okay

It'll give 0px, if the image failed to load otherwise it'll give the width and height of the actual image, And if you want to access the attributes like left, right, top, bottom for these attributes we need to set image position to absolute then we can access.

Comment: Wow. The img doesn't shown. Also doesn't give any style property (img.style.display - gives none)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.naturalWidth` & `.naturalHeight` to get the actual size of image

```
     function foo(element){
if(element){
    var el=document.querySelector(element);
    var img=el.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    alert(img.naturalWidth );
}
}
foo("#theid");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/1w9udsmf/7/)

Comment: `natural` Width and Height should be identical to `client` Width and Height, assuming the image hasn't been resized.  @RufatNuriev, if @vikrantsingh's answer doesn't solve your problem, and your image is loading, check your console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: @RufatNuriev did you check the fiddle ??http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/1w9udsmf/7/. It's working

Answer (score 0):

Image height/width is always returned 0px unless defined in CSS.

Try this piece of code, but you are loading the image again in this case (could be cached, but still).

```
var image = new Image();

// replace with appropriate library method
image.addEventListener("load", function() {
    //get image height/width here
}, false);

image.src = el.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the element offsetWidth

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anmrhL9v/) and the code:

```
function foo(element) {
    if (element) {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        alert(el.offsetWidth);
    }
}
foo("theid");
```

Note that I have used the document.getElementById only as that will get the element. No need to have getElementsByTagName in this case. And do not prefix the id with a '#' as that notation is of jquery not javascript.